# Lazy way of comparing ISA on code length

Tags: computer-architecture, compilers

I hope this is not too broad. I need to evaluate about 8 different ISA targets for about 12 specs. The only metric I'm intersted in is size of the output bytecode. Moreover, I'm only interested in relationship between code size for different targets, so I don't particualarly care about optimizing the code. My background is in the hardware engineering, so I don't relish the prospect of going into LLVM backend too deep. Is there an easier way to generate (non-optimal) byte code for different ISA targets?

Comment: If you're not generating decently optimized bytecode, what is your comparison based on? "Hey, guess what, this really bad code for target 1 is bigger than this well-written code for target 2!"

Comment: Optimization for performance will effect code size (e.g., CSE tends to reduce code size, inlining and loop unrolling typically increase code size, strength reduction can increase code size (e.g., multiplication by constant --> shift and add)) and optimization for code size (e.g., procedural abstraction) can effect performance. Sadly, fairness is probably impractical; some ISAs are less compiler friendly (or have less mature compiler technology) and comparing hand-crafted assembly for microbenchmarks has significant issues. Workload match also matters.